# How to best use NHibernate's BeginTransaction is a loop?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My code is trying to do the following and causing locking issues as the transaction it is trying to commit is for large numbers of data items.

```
        using(var session = sManager.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var rows = 0;
                foreach (var idsChunk in total.Chunk(500))
                {
                  .... <Execute Update>
                }

                trans.Commit();
            }
        }
```

There are about 500K records and the above code locks the underlying table for significat amount of time. Wondering if moving foreach outside BeginTransation will lead to other issues?
Could you please suggest appropriate way of doning this?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with NHibernate's batching and FlushMode options?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on *why* you're using a transaction.  If the *whole batch* should fail, then there's not much you can do other than redesigning to use a bulk update instead of record-by-record with NHibernate (would reduce the amount of time the table is locked).  If one insert can fail without failing the whole batch then yes put the transaction *inside* the loop (and catch any exceptions)

Comment: Individual Execute statements in the loop can fail without impacting any other once. However, I seek two answers here;

1. Commiting too many transaction inside a for loop may cause any issues (in my case there will be about 1000). Or in other words, is it recommended to use as low transactions as possible?

2. Can I use one sessions and multiple transactions

Comment: as in the following case:
        using(var session = sManager.OpenSession())
        {   var rows = 0;
            foreach (var idsChunk in total.Chunk(500))
            {using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
                 {
                  .... <Execute Update>
                 }
                trans.Commit();
             }
        }

Comment: Yes but then what's the point of using a transaction?  Transactions are used to bundle multiple statements and rollback when an error occurs.